# Cluster validation parameters

Tags: r, validation, cluster-analysis

I am using the clValid package to try and determining the best cluster approach and number of clusters. In the package it is possible to specify a number of methods, which are taken from other packages, e.g. cluster, Kohonen. In the documentation for clValid it appears that it is possible to pass arguments to clustering functions "... Additional arguments to pass to the clustering functions". I am using this functionality to change the kmeans algorithm to Llyod. However this is unknown to the clara algorithm and an error occurs.

```
library(clValid)
intern <- clValid(ycomplete.df,
          6:10,
          clMethods=c("clara","kmeans"),
          validation="internal",
          maxitems=17000)
Warning message:
Quick-TRANSfer stage steps exceeded maximum (= 821050) 
intern <- clValid(ycomplete.df,
          6:10,
          clMethods=c("clara","kmeans"),
          validation="internal",
          maxitems=17000,
          algorithm="Lloyd")
 Error in clara(mat, nc, metric = ifelse(metric == "correlation", "euclidean",  : 
  unused argument (algorithm = "Lloyd")
```

Clearly the clara algorithm does not understand the algorithm argument, which is only relevant to the kmeans method. Is there a way to specify each methods' arguments and have them ignored by the others?

Comment: the error message means, `algorithm` is not a parameter in the function `clValid()` signature. In more simple terms, look at the help file for this function like `help(clValid)` and you will note that there is no option of `algorithm` in it.

Comment: But there is an "algorithm" parameter for one of the ClMethods to use, kmeans. Hence it is not rejected by kmeans but is rejected by clara. If I run the above without clara as a clMethod, then all progresses fine, with kmeans using the Lloyd algorithm.